# How can I create an application that runs on my desktop toolbar?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

This might go as a very silly question but I don't even know the proper naming for the desktop's place:

I'd like to make an Application like Steam or Docker Desktop that runs on my taskbar and maintains certain state. Just a hello world

[[image: Screenshot for reference1]

Comment: For Windows? You're not going to be able to do it the same way for different platforms.

Comment: That's the whole point of kotlin multiplatform. Write `expect` and `actual` statements to provide implementations for Linux, Windows and Mac. Just to try it out. It may exist a solution already for JVM? That's why I am asking. I don't even know the actual name of what I am trying to implement

Comment: This place is called "tray"

Comment: looks like it does!